# cordova: app-preferences : TypeError: string is not a function

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have added the app-preferences plugin to my ionic project.
When Im running the on my android device and trying to store a key im getting the next error:

```
TypeError: string is not a function
at nativeExec (http://10.0.0.28:8100/plugins/cordova-plugin-app-preferences/www/apppreferences.js:175:11)
at AppPreferences.store (http://10.0.0.28:8100/plugins/cordova-plugin-app-preferences/www/apppreferences.js:187:3)
at Object.store (http://10.0.0.28:8100/lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js:9:10072)
at set (http://10.0.0.28:8100/js/just-go.js:1104:29)
at setUser (http://10.0.0.28:8100/js/just-go.js:1276:27)
at http://10.0.0.28:8100/js/just-go.js:1069:23
at processQueue (http://10.0.0.28:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27747:28)
at http://10.0.0.28:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27763:27
at Scope.$eval (http://10.0.0.28:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29026:28)
at Scope.$digest (http://10.0.0.28:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:28837:31)
```

This is my code sippet for storing the key:

```
  function set(key, value) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    console.log("Setting keys");
    $cordovaPreferences.store(key, value)
      .success(function(data) {
        console.log("key set");
        defer.resolve(data);
      })
      .error(function(error) {
        defer.reject(error);
        console.log("fail to set");
        console.log(error);
      });

    return defer.promise;
  };
```

anyone know what is the problem is?
the parameters I;m sending are "token" as key and some string as value..

PS is this possible to run with this plugin on browser? (for testing)
when i try to do something with it im getting plugin not enabled/

Comment: Could it be that you don't use store-method as expected? the signature of store is (ok-function, fail-function, key-string. value-string) accordinting to this source https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences

Answer (score 0):

The first and second param have to have functions instead of strings due to apppreferences.js file defines *store* method in this way:

```
 /**
 * Set a preference value
 *
 * @param {Function} successCallback The function to call when the value is set successfully
 * @param {Function} errorCallback The function to call when value is not set
 * @param {String} dict Dictionary for key (OPTIONAL)
 * @param {String} key Key
 * @param {String} value Value
 */
AppPreferences.prototype.store = platform.store || function (
successCallback, errorCallback, dict, key, value
    ) {
    ....
    }
```

And in your function *set* both strings key and value are passed as first and second param instead of functions.

Comment: Thanks that seems to be the problem.. do you also know if its possible to test that plugin on web? since it has local storage fallback it looks like its possible

Comment: You are welcome. If there is a local storage fallback then yes it should work in a modern browser as well but I've not tested this.

Comment: Im getting `Error: plugin in not enable`.. and ideas?

Comment: hard to tell without a specific stack trace output. But may be there is no fallback because as it states: "Execution on BlackBerry10 fallback using localStorage" only on BlackBerry there is a fallback in terms of the localStorage-API. what browser and OS did you test this plugin on?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my project. 
You build project using compiller for ECMAScript5.1 and this plugin use global variable from ECMAScript6(Promise). 
You must add compiller for ECMAScript6 to your IDE(for me it's WebStorm and I added babel, you can read this title http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/05/ecmascript-6-in-webstorm-transpiling/)
And after you must add es6-promise https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's a mismatch between your ngCordova and the plugin version. Haven't actually checked out if upgrading ngCordova works, but if you do not wish to upgrade ngCordova, you could use the plugin directly or modify ngCordova:

Replacing their storeResult promises with the callbacks as such

```
            // var storeResult;
            // if(arguments.length === 3){
            //     storeResult = $window.plugins.appPreferences.store(dict, key, value);
            // } else {
            //     storeResult = $window.plugins.appPreferences.store(key, value);
            // }

            // storeResult.then(ok, errorCallback);

            if(arguments.length === 3){
                storeResult = $window.plugins.appPreferences.store(ok, errorCallback, dict, key, value);
            } else {
                storeResult = $window.plugins.appPreferences.store(ok, errorCallback, key, value);
            }
```

in their **store**, **fetch** and **remove** functions